# Not able to list the events. resource = list(event['detail']['requestParameters']['evaluations'])[0]

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Getting the below error when i tried to list the S3 events.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'detail'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      30,
      "lambda_handler",
      "resource = list(event['detail']['requestParameters']['evaluations'])[0]"
    ]
  ]
}

Request ID:
"6ee059f2-556c-4483-a45f-f90238ed727e"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 6ee059f2-556c-4483-a45f-f90238ed727e Version: $LATEST
'detail': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 30, in lambda_handler
    resource = list(event['detail']['requestParameters']['evaluations'])[0]
KeyError: 'detail'

END RequestId: 6ee059f2-556c-4483-a45f-f90238ed727e
REPORT RequestId: 6ee059f2-556c-4483-a45f-f90238ed727e  Duration: 1491.42 ms    Billed Duration: 1500 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB  Init Duration: 165.73 ms
```

Code:

```
   import boto3
    from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
    import json
    import os
    ACL_RD_WARNING = "The S3 bucket ACL allows public read access."
    PLCY_RD_WARNING = "The S3 bucket policy allows public read access."
    ACL_WRT_WARNING = "The S3 bucket ACL allows public write access."
    PLCY_WRT_WARNING = "The S3 bucket policy allows public write access."
    RD_COMBO_WARNING = ACL_RD_WARNING + PLCY_RD_WARNING
    WRT_COMBO_WARNING = ACL_WRT_WARNING + PLCY_WRT_WARNING
    def policyNotifier(bucketName, s3client):
        try:
            bucketPolicy = s3client.get_bucket_policy(Bucket = bucketName)
            # notify that the bucket policy may need to be reviewed due to security concerns
            sns = boto3.client('sns')
            subject = "Potential compliance violation in " + bucketName + " bucket policy"
            "Potential bucket policy compliance violation. Please review: " + json.dumps(bucketPolicy['Policy']),
            # send SNS message with warning and bucket policy
            response = sns.publish(
                TopicArn = os.environ['TOPIC_ARN'],
                Subject = subject,
                Message = message
            )
        except ClientError as e:
            # error caught due to no bucket policy
            print("No bucket policy found; no alert sent.")
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        # instantiate Amazon S3 client
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        resource = list(event['detail']['requestParameters']['evaluations'])[0]
        bucketName = resource['complianceResourceId']
        complianceFailure = event['detail']['requestParameters']['evaluations'][0]['annotation']
        if(complianceFailure == ACL_RD_WARNING or complianceFailure == ACL_WRT_WARNING):
            s3.put_bucket_acl(Bucket = bucketName, ACL = 'private')
        elif(complianceFailure == PLCY_RD_WARNING or complianceFailure == PLCY_WRT_WARNING):
            policyNotifier(bucketName, s3)
        elif(complianceFailure == RD_COMBO_WARNING or complianceFailure == WRT_COMBO_WARNING):
            s3.put_bucket_acl(Bucket = bucketName, ACL = 'private')
            policyNotifier(bucketName, s3)
        return 0  # done
```

Copied code from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-config-to-monitor-for-and-respond-to-amazon-s3-buckets-allowing-public-access/

When I test the lambda function. getting above error.

New to python. Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're assuming that following path always exists in `event`: `event['detail']['requestParameters']['evaluations']`. Error tells you that `event` doesn't actually contain `detail` key.

What you should do is:

1. Make sure your test event corresponds to real life events you expect to trigger your lambda with
2. If it does, print `event` first to see its structure:

```
import json
...
print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))
```

It is entirely possible that event format changed since 2018 when this article was written.

3. In any case it's a good idea to enclose that statement in `try ... except` block to catch KeyError and exit gracefully